# Simple Ajax jQuery for CakePHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, croogo

I want to create a simple jQuery/Ajax/CakePHP script.

I have a list box with a button. When I chose something from the list and click the button I want to display a message representing a remaining purchase.

I read a lot of tutorials on Ajax with CakePHP I tried to do some, but they did not meet my needs.

Please, what are the detailed steps to do this?
I am a débutante.

Comment: Hi, What is your need ?

Comment: First : Use onchange function on list box,

Comment: I want when I selected an item in the list box displays a message the rest ($ rest)

Comment: Wirte onchage function in select box

Comment: I want something like the effect of $ this-> session-> flash ('add succefull');

Comment: just display a message that represents the total amount and the rest

Comment: You want display session flash message using ajax and jquery right ?

Comment: Did you try to google? Then you would have found http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/ Including live examples in the linked sandbox.

Comment: I tried several times but I have not done

Comment: please a simple example

Comment: pls refer this link-
http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/ajax_cakephp_contact_form

Answer (score 0):

I assume that have a controller and also define a method. Here I have create a method name as `test` in my `TestsController.php`. See that

```
class TestsController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array();
    public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time');

    public function test() {

        if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
            // selected item's id 
            echo   $value = $this->request->data('value_to_send');

            // put your logic 

            echo $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            die();
        }       
    }
}
```

Then I added  `test.ctp`  file under view/tests directory. Like as

```
$array_list =  array(
    '1' => 'Item 1',
    '2' => 'Item 2',
    '3' => 'Item 3',
    '4' => 'Item 4',
    '5' => 'Item 5',
);
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('list_box_id', array(
    'options'=> $array_list, 
    'id' => 'list_box_id', 
));

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#list_box_id').change(function() { 
           var selected_list_box_id =  $(this).val();      
           var requestUrl  = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'test')); ?>';
           $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{value_to_send:selected_list_box_id}, 
                url: requestUrl,
                success : function(data) {
                   alert(data);// will alert "ok"

                },
                error : function() {
                   alert("false");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Here I added jQuery code added to this page, You can stored in a
>   separate js file and I just give a simple code, You should modify as per you requirement.